# How to crawl Google Play website using scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, python-2.7, scrapy

#### Context:

1. I am trying to crawl a page on Google Play website
2. When I use the browser to browser that page and I scroll down using the browser scroll, I got new apps/items. That is absolutely an AJAX call.

#### Problem:

I don't know how to get -using Scrapy- the apps that I get when I scroll using browser's scroll.

#### What I have tried:

I crawled that page and print the response which is:

[image]

as you see, there is a loading signal, which doesn't appear using browser because it automatically calls an AJAX call.

#### Note:

I do know that we can use Scrapy to call HXR AJAX calls but I want my spider to crawl that page until there are no apps so the spider should (if there any) know the AJAX calls automatically.

I am using python 2.7.9 with Scrapy 0.26 on Windows 7 64bit

#### Note2:

I have already checked [this thread](https://github.com/anderson916/google-play-crawler/blob/master/crawler/spiders/bamSpider.py)

Many thanks

Comment: have you thought about using scrapy + webdriver ? You could make usage of webdriver to simulate the mouse movement which force the page reload

Comment: @aberna actually I have never heard of `webdriver` could you give me a link please

Comment: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ - http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a basic approach (not very pythonic) to show you a possible solution to your issue using Selenium Webdriver.

The basic idea is:

- create an headless browser istance (`webdriver.Firefox()`)
- make the istance load a page (`self.driver.get(response.url)`)
- search for an element in the page (this case is the copyright tag `<span class="copyright">©2015 Google</span>`) we already know it positioned in the bottom.
- while the element is not visible keep moving the focus inside the page to it

This way the page keep loading elements.

```
import scrapy
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider    

class googleplay(CrawlSpider):
    name = "googleplay"
    allowed_domains = ["play.google.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://play.google.com"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)      
        copyright = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('copyright')
        ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(copyright).perform()

        while not copyright.is_displayed():
            copyright = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('copyright')
            time.sleep(3) #to let page content loading
            ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(copyright).perform()

        #scrape by here
```

At the finish of the loop you are sure all the page has been loaded and you can the code for scraping contents

Documentation here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html